# Testing a Remote Client-Server Application

Tags: c#, testing, client-server

Yesterday, [I posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325824/remote-client-server-application-cannot-accept-incoming-messages) on some tips doing this Remote Client-Server Application in C#. So now, our group was able to create one. The problem is, we cannot think of ways on how we can test it since we are currently on different locations for our weekend break.

If anyone of you has any idea on how we can test it, please give us some hints.

Comment: Please tag homework questions as such. People are happy to help, but we need the right context :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have both client and server programs, you can simply run them both on same PC and test them just like they would be on different machines. (use "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" as IP address of server)

It's enough to test program algorithm, and once it work on same PC, it should actually work on any two machines over internet/LAN.

Of course you should understand how networking actually works. Whoever you are connecting, must be visible to you. If you are going to connect via internet, server's IP address might not be enough. Something like http://www.showmyipaddress.com/ might show ISP's front, "white" address. And user, who run the server might have "grey" IP address, behind a NAT. So if you are going to use something like showmyipaddress.com , check your real IP address by typing "ipconfig -all" in windows command line. If ipconfig shows same IP, there are high chances it will work over internet (just check your firewall).

Answer (score 1):

Have one of you setup the server, the other the client. Make sure your configurations match (use the server IP address, as you will probably not have a server name that can resolve via DNS).

Answer (score 1):

1. Browse to http://www.showmyipaddress.com
2. Your ip address is listed there
3. Tell your ipaddress to the others (You need to open a port in your FW/router if you have one)
4. Tell them to change localhost to your ipaddress in the application and then connect.

Answer (score 1):

you can use VMWare and run virtual machine (it's your choice), and run the server and the client in the same machine.
or you can run it on the same machine, just run : "ipconfig" on the command prompt ! get the IP and use it, or in some languages you can use the keyword "localhost", good luck